# Cannot parse crontab with tabs as field delimiters with Python's crontab package

Tags: python, cron

I am parsing an `/etc/crontab` (from a Debian 7.10 host) with Python's [`crontab`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) package.

I slightly misparses lines where the user field is surrounded by tabs (`CTRL+I`, not spaces). Yet `crontab(5)` states:

> The fields may be separated by spaces or tabs.

Have I encountered a bug in Python's `crontab` package or am I supposed to use e.g. a switch that enables tabs as delimiters?

The [source code](https://git.launchpad.net/python-crontab/tree/crontab.py) for `crontab` (lines 109-111) uses `\s` in its regular expressions, which is evidence against this being a bug. I am using version 2.2.8 of the package with Python 3 inside a virtualenv.

Comment: What is the symptom of the misparsing?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It gulps the first part ("field") of the command in affected lines (probably parsing its as group).

Comment: You should probably show how exactly you're using it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. In a very straightforward manner: `cron = CronTab(tabfile=filename, user=False)`.